# Using types with Storybook and Sveltekit

Tags: typescript, svelte, storybook, sveltekit

I am trying to use storybook together with typescript and sveltekit,though this has given me some issues that I cannot seem to help myself out of.

```
import Modal from './Modal.svelte'

export default {
  title: 'Modal',
  component: Modal,
}

const Template = (args: any) => ({
  component: Modal,
  props: args,
})

export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
  text: 'Hello World',
}
```

The above code gives me the following error on the line `Primary.args = {` :

`Property 'args' does not exist on type '(args: any) => { component: typeof default; props: any; }'.`

The storybook guide does not seem to take types into account when using svelte.
https://storybook.js.org/docs/svelte/get-started/whats-a-story.
So I'm not quite sure how to handle this.

Comment: `(Primary as any).args = { ... }` is one of the solution.